# SQL Query Invalid Object name via linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, linked-server

When I try the following query from Server3

```
Select * 
from [server1].[database1].[dbo].[tableX]
```

I recieve an an error of

> Invalid Object Name

But when I execute the same query from Server2 the query works. Both are MSSQL 2000

UPDATE: When i tried to query a different table on server1 from server3

```
Select * 
from [server1].[database1].[dbo].[tableY]
```

from Server3 it works. Its just tableX wont work

Comment: Is server1 configured as a linked server on server2?

Comment: You need to research Linked Servers. Also, you need to seriously consider upgrading your environment. The extended lifecycle support for SQL Server 2000 ended **4.5 years ago**.

Comment: is the linked server in both Server2 and Server3 refer to the same server ? How about user rights ? does the user in Server3 has access to the table in Server1 ?

Comment: Guys ive check the right and permission and its all good. Same with the linked Servers. But ive got an update. Please do check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that tableX exists on the destination server then check that a linked server is present

Run:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.servers;
```

On Server2 and Server3 and see if the results are the same. This will show name of the host server along with any other linked servers that may exist. The Microsoft Doc is [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql).

If there isn't a linked server set up on Server3 then create one, The Microsoft docs are [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine), but if you Google how to then there are plenty of guides out there.

And think about upgrading from SQL SERVER 2000 is was [desupported](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cdnitmanagers/2012/12/06/sql-server-2000-end-of-support-april-2013/) April 2013